# Load front-page.php from plugin to override themes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin and thought that to load `front-page.php` from my plugin, all I had to do was add it to the root directory like I would in a custom theme, but that has not been the case.

How do I get `front-page.php` from my plugin to load and override any theme/child themes?

I've tried to use the `locate_template` override from [the codex here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template#Loading_a_template_in_a_plugin.2C_but_allowing_theme_and_child_theme_to_override_template), but it only flashes my `front-page.php` and then defaults to index.php.

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the template include wordpress function. You do so when using the 'template_include' filter within your themes or plugins `function.php`.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'template_override');
function template_override($template) {
  if (is_front_page()) {
    return TEMPLATE_PATH . 'filename.php';
  }
  // default wordpress behavior
  return $template;
}
```

You also could run trouble when the static frontpage setting is configured.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page